# Qt: Shut down the application when the user doesn't a supported OpenGL version

Tags: qt, opengl, webengine

I use Qt 5.7 with Web Engine in my application. The application has thousands of users and for some of them the whole application crashes (with the classic Windows "app.exe has stopped working" dialog) when trying to load a webpage in my webview. Upon doing some digging, I discovered it crashes for users that don't have OpenGL 2+.

Is there a way to determine the user's OpenGL version and shut down the application (or write a message to them, I'd take care of that) if the version is not supported? I tried using `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, but that means including yet another QT library in an already not so small application.

Comment: Angle might help.

Comment: @Ober.. It is a good library that Qt has come up with.... But the OP has to modify most of his gl functions to make them work with angle.

Comment: Since you only need this one function, maybe you could extract a small portion from the sources and include in your program

Comment: I don't explicitely call any GL functions, Web Engine does that for me.